# parseInt() function is adding 1 to my integer, and thus changing the number. What is going on?

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation, parseint

I have encountered some behaviour with the JavaScript `parseInt` function that I have never seen before. I am trying to convert a string to an integer. But the `parseInt` function is adding 1 to it. The values for `temp` and `k` are calculated in a prior step of my program, here is my code:

```
let temp = 918367346938775;
let k = 5;

console.log("This is temp:", temp);
console.log("This is k:", k);
let concatNumber = temp.toString() + k.toString();
console.log("This is concatNumber in string form:", concatNumber);
console.log("This is concatNumber in integer form using parseInt:", parseInt(concatNumber, 10));
console.log("This is concatNumber in integer form multiplying by 1:", concatNumber * 1);
```

Here is a picture of the console.log:

[image: Console Log]

The string concatenation correctly gives me the number I am expecting which is: 9183673469387755.

However once that number is converted to an integer via `parseInt` I get 9183673469387756.

I have also attempted to multiply the string by just 1, but I also get the incorrect 9183673469387756 number.

Here is my PlayCodeIO sample:

https://playcode.io/1741191

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your concatenated number is too big to be represented as an integer in a JavaScript number.

Comment: Also it's a little weird to be doing this with strings; you can multiply a number by 10 and add a single digit numerically. However, in this case, you're still going to be exceeding the range of "safe" integers of 64-bit floating point values.

Comment: You can try BigInt in modern JavaScript environments.

Comment: TL;DR - `9183673469387755 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: Hey guys I modified my code to be:
let temp = 918367346938775;
let k = 5;
let concatNumber = BigInt(temp * 10 + k);
console.log(concatNumber)

but the console output is still: 9183673469387756n. As opposed to 9183673469387755n (which is what I was expecting).

Comment: Ohhh so, it is not possible to do this? Because:

9183673469387755 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ?

Comment: @ashcohen26 Don't convert to BigInt **after** the numerical error has happened. You must start with `temp = 918367346938775n` already

Comment: @Bergi, it worked as expected in PlayCodeIO. However in my actual program, temp is calculated with variables. Specifically `temp = n * newK`. Also, `newK` is originally initialized as `k`. Both `n` and `k` are always single digit constants. But both `temp` and `newK` will eventually become BigInt. How can I handle that if `temp` and `newK` originally start as numbers, but eventually become BigInt?

Comment: Do everything with BigInt from the beginning.

Comment: @ashcohen26 Ideally, you already start with `n` and `k` as bigints - makes everything simpler. Alternatively, if you know their values are always safe integers, keep them as numbers, but always convert them to bigints before usage (`newK = BigInt(k)`, `temp = BigInt(n) * newK` etc). You may do the conversion anywhere along the way, it just needs to happen *before* the values get out of the safe range; so you always need to know in which range the possible values for a variable are.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!! I successfully have my entire program working as expected. The last key in the puzzle was starting as BigInt